# Convert user entered true azimuth to magnetic azimuth

Tags: ios, compass-geolocation, heading

I was wondering if there is a way to use `CLHeading` or `CLLocationDirection` to convert between true and magnetic azimuth for a USER entered value.

In a normal scenario with plenty of examples on SO, we can use `didUpdateHeading:(CLocation) newHeading` with `newHeading.magneticHeading` or `trueHeading` to get those values when we want the device bearing/heading. Both `trueHeading` and `magneticHeading` are read only properties.
However what I need is to provide a user entered true azimuth to `CLocation` or something else and return the magnetic value corresponding to the input.

One way to do that is to get the updated magnetic field model of the earth from NOAA (or other sources) and write code to do this calculation based on the user location. However this has many drawbacks and requires constant updates to the model array in the app code since the model changes all the time. Using any built-in model would be great...

**UPDATE (More Information to understand declination):**

I tested the declination for the DC area and it correctly returned -10.7 degrees with the simple function in the answer by @rokjarc shown below. For reference on the  declination in the US, please see the following map (Image Source - NOAA):
[image]

Later I will be deploying this on a friend's device in Houston, TX area where the declination is 2 degrees to further confirm.

For those who wonder, when you use Apple's MapKit, the map is always oriented so that true north is situated at the top of the map -- source --
(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/)
With the above information, you should always use true heading and NOT magnetic if displaying a POI with a bearing or azimuth relative to a location like what I was trying to achieve...

**NOTE:** Declination changes all the time (you may have heard of pole shift). If you test this in 2016 for example, DC may have a declination of -5 or -20 etc instead of the current -10. When using this method to calculate the declination you do not have to worry about changes in declination over time since the compass (I believe) will sense the magnetic field of the earth and return the correct `heading.magneticHeading`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the last paragraph of your question it seems that you are interested in conversion of arbitrary magnetic heading to true heading on **current location** of the user.

In this case you can assign an ivar (or property) called `variation` and update regulary in `didUpdateHeading:`.

```
//instantiated as ivars or properties:

NSDate *variationTimestamp;
double variation; //or CLLocationDirection
CLLocationManager *locationManager;   

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    CLLocation *location = locationManager.location;

    //check if location is valid - it has to be for variation data to be valid too

    if ((newHeading.headingAccuracy > 0) && (location.horizontalAccuracy > 0))
    {
        variation = newHeading.trueHeading - newHeading.magneticHeading;
        variationTimestamp = newHeading.timestamp;
    }
}
```

Since magnetic variation if an `f(location)` - it is the same for all magnetic headings on the same location - you can use this `variation` for calculations with user input.

The obvious drawback is that you have to have fresh location/heading data. Note: besides enabling heading updates you have to also **enable location updates**.

Comment: Keep in mind that the 1st paragraph talks about using a "user entered location", not the current location.

Comment: It says "user entered value" - i assume it's a value for magnetic heading. If OP wants to do calculation on an arbitrary (entered) location then of course this method won't be of any use.

Comment: @rokjarc thank you for your answer, but as rmaddy says, I asked for a user entered value, such as a keyed in value of TRUE heading and I want to convert it to magnetic heading.

Comment: so you want user to enter location (coordinates) and heading?

Comment: @rokjarc, yes and no, I want user to enter heading and coordinates can be ready using didUpdateLocaiton and CLocation... The thing about magnetic declination is that it varies depending on where you are on earth. For example a true azimuth of 220 is equivalent to 230 if you're in Washington, DC or 250 if you're say in Alaska...

Comment: @rokjarc BUT I think  I may be able to use what you typed in to CONCLUDE the declination.... Then take that declination and apply it to the user entered TRUE heading/azimuth and do a +/- on it to get the magnetic heading/azimuth... Let me try that tonight and then I'll mark if this is an answer... Thanks again!

Comment: Of course - that is why you have to have locationUpdates enabled. And from difference between retrieved magnetic and true course you calculate magnetic variation for that specific location. I do that in two of my apps. And then you can applicate calculated variation on any (user entered) magnetic heading.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely as you get realtime location updates, the true heading is being derived from the GPS data as you move from one point to another while the magnetic heading is coming from the compass. This of course only works in realtime on the user's current location.

The Core Location framework has no API to give you the magnetic variation for an arbitrary location. The solution described in your last paragraph is your only viable solution.

Keep in mind that there can't be a built-in model for the reason you already mention - it changes.

Comment: I may be able to use the variation calculated in rokjarc answer above to add it or subtract it from user entered TRUE value to convert it to magnetic... Don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the license notes of Apples iphone, you get a list of all open source they use in iphone. (Menu Common->Info->Copyright->License)
One of that is the geomagnetic earth modell, developped by NOAA. You can download the source and implement that too:
Geomag: https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/WMM/

This would have the advantage that you can calculate the magnetic variation for any coordinate on world, not only the current one. For most places the relative change of the azimuth per year is known and specified, like in better topgraphic maps. You can then extrapolate to current time when knowing the date of the geo mag modell.

However in most cases it is sufficient to know the magnetic variation for current location.
In that case reading it from CLLocation is possible (as described by User rokjarc)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. The URL provided by apple seems outdated though. I ended using what rokjarc suggested although it would be nice to have a library/code to determine the deviation for any location in the world. I may revisit this topic at a later time...

Answer (score 1):

I needed a solution to find magnetic declination at a specified location in Swift, based on the World Magnetic Model.

Here is my implementation: https://github.com/kanchudeep/Geomagnetism-Swift

It's a simple single class which can be dropped into any project and used.

Comment: Your code is very useful for me, thank you ! I also need to calc magnetic declination because my app is used with standing vertically and faceup option of CLLocationManager.headingOrientation seems invalid.